# C++ Operator and Conversion Issues

Tags: c++

```
double mean(vector<Reading> temps)
{
// stub version
    double mean_temp;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< temps.size(); ++i) sum += temps[i];
    mean_temp = sum/temps.size();
    return (mean_temp);
}

double median(vector<Reading> temps)
{
// stub version
    double median_temp;
    sort (temps.begin(), temps.end());
    median_temp = temps[temps.size()/2];
    return (median_temp);
}
```

============================================

Result in errors:

```
proj4.cc: In function ‘double mean(Vector<Reading>)’:
proj4.cc:132: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘sum += temps.Vector<T>::operator[] [with T = Reading](((unsigned int)i))’
proj4.cc: In function ‘double median(Vector<Reading>)’:
proj4.cc:142: error: cannot convert ‘Reading’ to ‘double’ in assignment
```

=============================================

Full code below. I need to tackle these two errors before I can proceed

```
#include <bjarne/std_lib_facilities.h>

struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
    bool operator<(const Reading &r) const;
};

bool Reading::operator<(const Reading &r) const
{
// stub version

    vector<Reading> temps;
    sort (temps.begin(), temps.end());

}

/*
 * function declarations
 */

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Reading &r);

vector<Reading> get_temps();

double check_adjust_temp(double temperature, char scale);

double c_to_f(double temperature);

double mean(vector<Reading> temps);

double median(vector<Reading> temps);

void print_results(const vector<Reading>& temps, double mean_temp, 
           double median_temp);

int main()
    try
    {
        vector<Reading> temps = get_temps();
        if (temps.size() == 0) error("no temperatures given!");
        double mean_temp = mean(temps);
        sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
        double median_temp = median(temps);
        print_results(temps, mean_temp, median_temp);
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n'; 
    return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
    cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n"; 
    return 2;
    }

/*
 * function definitions
 */

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Reading &r)
{
// stub version

/*

 */
    return ost; 
}

vector<Reading> get_temps()
{
// stub version
    cout << "Please enter name of input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist(name.c_str());
    if(!ist) error("can't open input file ", name);

    vector<Reading> temps;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    while (ist >> hour >> temperature){
    if (hour <0 || 23 <hour) error("hour out of range");
    temps.push_back( Reading(hour,temperature));
    }

}

double check_adjust_temp(double temperature, char scale)
{
// stub version

    if (scale== 'c' || 'C'){

    return c_to_f(temperature);
    }
    else if (scale== 'f' || 'F')  {

    return temperature;
    }
    else {

    error("Wrong input type");
    }
}

double c_to_f(double temperature)
{
// stub version
    double c;
    c = ((temperature * (9.0/5)) + 32);
    return (c);
}

double mean(vector<Reading> temps)
{
// stub version
    double mean_temp;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< temps.size(); ++i) sum += temps[i];
    mean_temp = sum/temps.size();
    return (mean_temp);
}

double median(vector<Reading> temps)
{
// stub version
    double median_temp;
    sort (temps.begin(), temps.end());
    median_temp = temps[temps.size()/2];
    return (median_temp);
}

void print_results(const vector<Reading>& temps, double mean_temp, 
           double median_temp)
{
// stub version
    cout << "The sorted temperatures are:\n";
    cout << get_temps;
    cout << "The mean temperature is " << mean_temp << ".\n";
    cout << "The median temperature is " << median_temp << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PsychicsOverflow.com: what's a "Reading" when it's at home?

Comment: BTW- you'd probably want to make those functions accept a `const vector<Reading>&` instead of a `vector<Reading>` in order to make sure they won't be copied during a function call.

Comment: @Kos: `mean()` should probably take a `const vector<Reading>&`, yes.  But as currently implemented, `median()` should in fact take its argument by value, creating a copy that can be sorted without creating surprises for anyone else.

Comment: Median can be calculated in O(n) without sorting, AFAIK? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm - just mentioning, IDK what would be actually faster here.

Answer (score 4):

Define a conversion operator for Reading:

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
    bool operator<(const Reading &r) const;
    operator double() { return temperature; }
};
```

Or, better (via the Principle of Least Astonishment), just change the usage of your class:

```
// was:
sum += temps[i];
//change to:
sum += temps[i].temperature;

// was:
median_temp = temps[temps.size()/2];
//change to:
median_temp = temps[temps.size()/2].temperature;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute an addition between an instance of a `class Reading` and a `double`. This doesn't work as long as you don't provide either a default conversion path from `Reading` to `double`:

```
Reading::operator double() const { return temperature; }
```

or by providing proper global operator+() overloads:

```
double operator+(Reading const&, double);
double operator+(double, Reading const&);
```

The second error should be solvable with the `Reading::operator double()` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to sum up Reading objects into a double variable!

```
sum += temps[i];
```

sum type is double while temps[i] returns Reading object, you cannot sum `double` and `Reading` object since they belong to different types, you must define an overload of **plus** operator and make the compiler *understand how this is done*.

Comment: Overloading operator plus is not really the best approach here, because then you'd still need to overload minus, multiply, etc, etc. It's better to just let the compiler know "how to make a number out of this object" via the conversion operator and all the arithmetical ops will magically start to work. But then, it's not obvious "what is the numerical value of a record" (might be temperature, might be time), and that's why I recommend to just refer to the field explicitly - clear and simple.

Comment: I don't think so. If this is the case, then instead of operator overloading, we could have written getter/setter for each data member. Overloading operators is important for many reasons, the most important one I think is specializing the semantic of the operator according to the operand type; Summing two date objects for example is different semantically from summing a date to an integer, using the same plus operator for both situations is far more intuitive, scalable, and elegant than exposing the data members or using different flavors of getter/setter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing operator+= for the class Reading